# what is alloc.h?

Tags: c, header-files

what is `alloc.h`? some questions on SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7006256/1526667) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4395415/1526667) have included `alloc.h`.

but, [when  i tried to include it gcc gives error](http://ideone.com/o35Hr)  as `error: alloc.h: No such file or directory`

Has such file ever existed or those questions have included it just by mistake?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a header file that declares memory-management functions like `malloc`, `free`, `realloc`.

That header file is deprecated.

For C use

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

For C++ use

```
#include <memory>
```

Comment: gcc 4.3 removed this header file. Read more here: http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/porting_to.html

Answer (score 11):

It's for dynamic memory allocation, but it isn't a ANSI C standard library.
If you are using gcc then use stdlib for dynamic memory allocation:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

For some more information, have a look [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Platform_Reference/alloc.h).

If you read carefully the question you have linked, actually the problem was exactly trying to compile with gcc including that header. So don't use it.